Why git clone succeed after renaming the repository name

A gitlab repository "moved" to a new location (different repo name, different user). Moved means that another user has created a new repository, and pushed the files to the new repository. Now all users, scripts should point to the new repo. This is not the issue but to make it clear the new repository URL is:
https://gitlab.com/userName2/NewRepoName

Now I want the following git clone command pointing to the original repository to fail
git clone https://gitlab.com/userName/OriginalRepoName.git

Within the gitlab web site, I have renamed the original repository and also changed its path.
Yet the project itself still exists (only with a different name and URL). So:
The previous project name: OriginalRepoName.
The current project name: OldRepoName.
The previous project url was: https://gitlab.com/userName/OriginalRepoName
The current project url is now: https://gitlab.com/userName/OLDRepoName


The problem:
git clone https://gitlab.com/userName/OriginalRepoName.git still succeed and the project is being cloned.
How come?
Also tried
I found this post but I am not sure I understand how it goes. It mentions gitlab keeps track of it ( to still enable git clone using the OriginalRepoName), but I can not find in git lab anything referring it.
I also trying to simply disable git clone for this repository but didnt find how to do that.
Please advise.
